# Microsoft OneNote - Annotate and print PDF "printout"

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-onenote, annotations

**My End Goal**

I'm trying to use Microsoft OneNote to annotate and print a PDF. For example, I'd like to write and draw on top of the PDF. Then, I want to print the PDF with my annotations.

**What I've Tried So Far**

I've inserted my PDF into a OneNote note using the Insert > File Printout feature. This loads the pages of my PDF as images. I am able to annotate the images as I want. But when I go to print the note, the PDF images do not fill up the print pages, so each page of my original PDF is actually split into several printed pages. I've tried playing around with my page margins, but I can't seem to get it right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we assume that the annotations features in Acrobat Reader are insufficient to your needs? Also, just a note on OneNote: It isn't designed for page layout and printing, as you've no doubt become aware.

Comment: One option that may bridge the gap could be PowerPoint. It has enough graphical elements it could work for annotating, and it has just enough page layout built into its design that it could work to keep things better paginated.

Comment: @music2myear Good point. I was not aware that Acrobat Reader supported drawing annotations. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Annotation capability built-in to Adobe Acrobat (including the free Reader product) may have the necessary capability OP is looking for.

One Note, by default, is not a page-aware application, and there is not a way I am aware of to force it to paginate in a particular way. One Note is about information storage and retrieval, and it is not about laying out that information on physical paper in a meaningful or orderly way.

Another option beginning with Office 2016 is to open PDFs in Microsoft Word, which DOES support pagination and some limited free-hand drawing capability.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to set up an empty word doc with the  Select everything <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> which should pick up the pdf pages and annotations, copy them <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>),then paste them into an empty word doc. You can then print the word doc to a pdf.

The pasted page is smaller than A4, so you may wish to crop the PDF afterwards or use a smaller page size in word.